# Safari 8 on iOS sends empty file body in cross-domain multipart POST

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I use following code to send a request:

```
var file = $('input').prop('files')[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('post', 'http://192.168.0.105:8000/');
req.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  console.log(this.readyState, this.status, this);
};
req.send(formData);
```

Where 192.168.0.105 is IP of machine with `netcat -l 8000` running. And this is netcat output:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.105:8000
Referer: http://jsbin.com/hegini/2
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLiJ1hASemXC7HMj4
Content-Length: 63594
Accept-Language: ru
Origin: http://jsbin.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A365 Safari/600.1.4

------WebKitFormBoundaryLiJ1hASemXC7HMj4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryLiJ1hASemXC7HMj4--
```

As you can see, file body is empty, but `Content-Length` is right.

This is online example: http://jsbin.com/hegini/2/watch